# Literature request for pinning the corner singularities in finite differences

Tags: finite-difference, stability

Corner singularities cause instability of finite difference solutions. They occur at the intersection of boundary conditions. I was recently going through an online video course that was explaining how to use the staggered grid and the marker and cell algorithm to solve the lid-driven cavity Navier-Stokes equations. There was just a mention that the corner singularity problem can be solved using the "pinning" method.

I have tried to find more information about this pinning method, but I wasn't able to find it in any literature. Can you please recommend me some literature where I can read how to use this pinning method to solve corner singularities? I would like to know when is it usable, how it works, and how much deviation of the numerical solution it causes. Also, if you know of any literature on some other methods for solving corner singularities in finite differences, please recommend me.

Comment: I read about corner singularities in J.P. Boyd's book ["Cheybeshev and Fourier Spectral Methods"](https://depts.washington.edu/ph506/Boyd.pdf) Chapter 6.12, and 16.5. That book isn't about finite differences but the problem is not limited to finite differences anyways. This and the references therein could serve as a starting point for your literature search.

Comment: Thank you very much :D